# Unable to set label colour in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a tableview that contains two cells. Now these cells contain labels and I want to change the colour of these label.

My code:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CheckerCell";
CustomCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.titleLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.subTitleLabel.text=[subTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:78/255.0 green:157/255.0 blue:19/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:167/255.0 green:19/255.0 blue:43/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        }
    }
```

What am i missing here? Also this code is in base class. does it matter?

Please guide.

Comment: are you set text to labels ?

Comment: The link provided above sets the cell not to be user interactive. I can't do so..

Answer (score 4):

You should **first create your cell**:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

 if( !cell ) {

     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
 if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:78/255.0 green:157/255.0 blue:19/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:167/255.0 green:19/255.0 blue:43/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
   }
}
```

Also checkout [other functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3aforIndexPath%3a) to dequeue cells as well and see which best fits your need here.

**EDIT:**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CheckerCell";
     CustomCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     // See this missing piece of code to create a cell
     if( !cell ) {

             cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SomeTableViewCellDesignedFromXIB" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]; 
     }
     // See this missing piece of code 

     cell.titleLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.subTitleLabel.text=[subTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:78/255.0 green:157/255.0 blue:19/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:167/255.0 green:19/255.0 blue:43/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Lalit_vicky, check updates.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:78/255.0 green:157/255.0 blue:19/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
       cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:167/255.0 green:19/255.0 blue:43/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"your text here";


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Pls see my edit @aklesh Rathaur

Comment: @Lalit_vicky if you r using custom cell then u need to change this to custom cell.

Comment: will you mind to help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the cell in the first place, which you need to do in order to set the colour

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString static * identifiderPlain = @"CellPlain";

    UITableViewCell * cell;


    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifiderPlain];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifiderPlain];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(78.0f/255.0f) green:(157.0f/255.0f) blue:(19.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(167.0f/255.0f) green:(19.0f/255.0f) blue:(43.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use This

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:78/255.0 green:157/255.0 blue:19/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: As-per question i replay answer So why downvote.